# Is it possible to run powershell using SSH from remote-host?

Tags: powershell-remoting, powershell-3.0

Is it possible to run powershell script using "ssh" or any protocol from remote-host (Linux)?

Followed these steps:

1. Have 'freeSHd' installed which runs ssh/ telnet services.
2. Able to connect Windows 2008R2 host thru SSH.
3. Able to run (powershell.exe) and entered into powershell environment.
4. Set the Execution Policy to 'Restricted' (Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted) before running the powershell script.
5. Ran the script & "C:\Scripts\setUp.ps1"
6. Received following error:

The term 'Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. t C:\Scripts\setUp.ps1:1 char:26
+ Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust <<<<  -Name 'RP' -MetadataURL 'https://rphost:443/fed/sp/metadata'; + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Also tried running like this and resulted in same error:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command ". 'C:\Scripts\setUp.ps1'"

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks
GKS